How can I put baseboards/skirting over wall expansion joints?
I’m assuming these are expansion joints, I’m about to put down my floors. They protrude about 1/4 inch out the wall. How can I run my baseboards evenly along these?


Drywall does not use expansion joints.  At least not that I know of.  Usually joints that bad is a sign the wall/studs behind it was not built straight/some studs are sticking out more.

That's not drywall, @crip659. It appears to be one of the "basement finishing systems" that uses a molded joint strip between panels.

If ecnerwal is right, those strips are just decorative not for expansion, and I think so too, the solution is to cut them to the height of the baseboard so you can just run the baseboard straight across the gap.  Maybe the vendor sells baseboard that matches the look of the strips?  Try to find instructions.

You will need to cut and "step" the moulding.
You have the perfect example right here 
